# Replace after specific text

Tags: r

I would like to remove after specific text in rows whatever exist.

I use this:

```
dframe$col1 <- gsub("Stock Amazon|Or Another|Google","",dframe$col1)
```

but it removes the whole row and not whatever after the string. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Hi Nathalie! Can you provide some example data and your current vs expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, as you say, you want to remove whatever text exists **after** some text, then lookaround may help you:

**DATA**:

```
text <- c("some text Stock Amazon more text", "text again Or Another text", "yet more Google and this")
```

**SOLUTION**:

This pattern says, "if you see `Stock Amazon` or `Or Another` or `Google`on the left delete whatever comes next":

```
gsub("(?<=Stock Amazon|Or Another|Google).*", "", text, perl = T)
[1] "some text Stock Amazon" "text again Or Another"  "yet more Google"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to answer without an example, but here is a pointer using the stringr library:

```r
library(tidyverse)
dframe <- dframe %>%
  mutate(col1 = str_extract(col1, "Your text"))
```

Hope it helps.